# Creating an ajax function to load portions of a page jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to create a function that I could just call from a mouseclick to load portions of a page using jQuery. I've managed to get the code inside the function to work without the use of a function, but as soon as I try to implement it using a function the page that's supposed to load goes to a new page rather than the portion where "Greeting" is. Check it out here: http://mvcsf.com/portfolios/ (Click on Your Profile and you'll see what I mean)

HTML:

```
<div id="bottomContent">
            <div id="side-bar"> 
                <ul class="side-nav">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption active" id="home"><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption" id="changeDetails"><a href="membersProfileChange.php">Your Profile</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption" id="signedUpEvents"><a href="#">Registered Events</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption" id="upcomingEvents"><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>   
           </div>
           <div id="bottomMainContent">
                <h1> Greetings!</h1>
           </div>
       </div>
```

jQuery: (Edited based upon Tieson's and Ninja's suggestion)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuOption').click(function(e) {
    $('.menuOption').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');     
    e.preventDefault();
    linkURL = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#bottomMainContent").load(linkURL);
     $("#content").animate({
        height:$("#bottomContent").height() + 300
    },600);
});
});
```

Comment: Why not just use what's already there?: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Try giving `return false` after ajax call

Comment: @TiesonT., I 've edited it using load but not too sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#changeDetails').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    linkURL = $(this).attr('href');
    returnAjaxPage(linkURL);
});
```

This should fix your problem. The issue here is that an anchor tag `<a></a>` by default redirect you to the url you specify in the `href` attribute. If you don't want it do to that you need to prevent that default action.

Comment: I combined yours and Tieson's suggestion together to make what I have above but I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you pass the e variable in your callback function of the click event ?

Comment: Are you talking about `e`?

Comment: yes it is the event object variable, it can be anything (just so that you know)

Comment: @Andrew Yes. It's not redirecting, but simply returning an entire page. You need to filter the result, as shown here: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Ajax methods are not blocking, so you probably want to move your animation inside of the callback of the `.load()` call; something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.menuOption').on('click', function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.menuOption').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        linkURL = $(this).attr('href');

         $("#bottomMainContent").load(linkURL + ' #your-filter-fragment', function(response, status, jqxhr){
            $("#content").animate({
                height:$("#bottomContent").height() + 300
            },600);
        });
    });
});
```

The parameters of the callback function can be used to perform some error-handling, as necessary.